# Linux: Timing during recording/playing sound

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, timing, recording

I have a more general question, regarding timing in a standard Linux-OS dealing with playing sound and receiving data over a serial port.

In the moment, I'm reading a PCM-Signal arriving over a USB-to-Serial Bridge (pl2303) which is recorded, encoded and sent from a FPGA.

Now, I need to create "peaks" at a known position in the recorded soundstream, and plan to play a soundfile from the same machine which is recording at a known moment. The peak has to begin and stop inside windows of maximal 50ms, it's length could be ~200ms...

Now, my question is: How precise can I expect the timing to be? I know, that several components add "unkown lag", jitter:

- USB-to-Serial Bridge collects ~20 bytes from the serial side before sending them to the USB-side (at 230400Baud this results in ~1ms)
- If I call "`sleep 1; mpg123 $MP3FILE` &" directly before my recording software, the Linux-Kernel will schedule them differenty (maybe this causes a few 10ms, depending on system load?)
- The soundcard/driver will maybe add some more unkown lag...
- Will tricks like "nice" or "sched_setscheduler" add value in my case?
- I could build an additional thread inside my recording sofware, which plays the sound. Doing this, the timing may be more precise, but I have a lot more work to do ...

Thanks a lot.

I will try it anyway, but I'm looking for some background toughts to understand and solve my upcoming problems better.

Comment: It turns out, that using "sudo chrt --fifo 99 ./experiment.sh" yields in an accuracy better than 10ms -- enough! No kernel-patching, no hardware-upgrade no fuzzy multithread-programming ;-)

fifo RT scheduling in activated in an ubuntu standard-kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I would imagine that your kernel would need to be rebuilt to allow the scheduler to reduce latency time in switching tasks a la multitasking, in kernels 2.6.x series, there's an option to make the kernel more smoother by making it pre-emptible.

- Go to Processor Type and features
- Pre-emption Model
- Select Preemptible kernel (low latency desktop)

This should streamline the timing and make the sounds appear smoother as a result of less jitters.

Try that and recompile the kernel again. There are of course, plenty of kernel patches that would reduce the timeslice for each task-switch to make it even more smoother, your mileage may vary depending on:

1. Processor speed - what processor is used?
2. Memory - how much RAM?
3. Disk input/output - the faster, the merrier

using those three factors combined, will have an influence on the scheduler and the multi-tasking features. The lower the latency, the more fine-grained it is.

Incidentally, there is a specialized linux distribution that is catered for capturing sound in real-time, I cannot remember the name of it, the kernel in that distribution was heavily patched to make sound capture very smooth.

Answer (score 0):

it's me again... After one restless night, I solved my strange timing-problems... My first edit is not completely correct, since what I posted was not 100% reproducible. After running some more tests, I can come up with the following Plot, showing timing accuracy:

[Results from analysis http://mega2000.de/~mzenzes/pics4web/2010-05-28_13-37-08_timingexperiment.png](http://mega2000.de/~mzenzes/pics4web/2010-05-28_13-37-08_timingexperiment.png)

I tried two different [ubuntu-kernels](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/kernel): `2.6.32-21-generic` and `2.6.32-10-rt`

I tried to achieve RT-scheduling: `sudo chrt --fifo 99 ./experimenter.sh`

And I tried to change powersaving-options: `echo {performance,conservative} | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

This resulted in 8 different tests, with 50 runs each. Here are the numbers:

```
                                   mean(peakPos)  std(peakPos) 
rt-kernel-fifo99-ondemand          0.97           0.0212 
rt-kernel-fifo99-performance       0.99           0.0040 
rt-kernel-ondemand                 0.91           0.1423 
rt-kernel-performance              0.96           0.0078 
standard-kernel-fifo99-ondemand    0.68           0.0177 
standard-kernel-fifo99-performance 0.72           0.0142 
standard-kernel-ondemand           0.69           0.0749 
standard-kernel-performance        0.69           0.0147
```